# CountVectorizer deleting features that only appear once

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm using the sklearn python package, and I am having trouble creating a `CountVectorizer` with a pre-created dictionary, where the `CountVectorizer` doesn't delete features that only appear once or don't appear at all.

Here is the sample code that I have:

```
train_count_vect, training_matrix, train_labels = setup_data(train_corpus, query, vocabulary=None)
test_count_vect, test_matrix, test_labels = setup_data(test_corpus, query, vocabulary=train_count_vect.get_feature_names())

print(len(train_count_vect.get_feature_names()))
print(len(test_count_vect.get_feature_names()))
```

`len(train_count_vect.get_feature_names())` outputs `89967`
`len(test_count_vect.get_feature_names())` outputs `9833`

Inside the `setup_data()` function, I am just initializing `CountVectorizer`. For training data, I'm initializing it without a preset vocabulary. Then, for test data, I'm initializing CountVectorizer with the vocabulary I retrieved from my training data.

How do I get the vocabularies to be the same lengths? I think sklearn is deleting features because they only appear once or don't appear at all in my test corpus. I need to have the same vocabulary because otherwise, my classifier will be of a different length from my test data points.

Comment: Could you please include the source code for `seup_data`? It's not really possible for us to figure out what's wrong without seeing that.

Comment: There should be only one CountVectorizer, not two. @SlaterTyranus 's answer explains why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it's impossible to say without actually seeing the source code of `setup_data`, but I have a pretty decent guess as to what is going on here. `sklearn` follows the `fit_transform` format, meaning there are two stages, specifically `fit`, and `transform`.

In the example of the `CountVectorizer` the `fit` stage effectively creates the vocabulary, and the `transform` step transforms your input text into that vocabulary space.

My guess is that you're calling `fit` on both datasets instead of just one, you need to be using the same "fitted" version of `CountVectorizer` on both if you want the results to line up. e.g.:

```
model = CountVectorizer()
transformed_train = model.fit_transform(train_corpus)
transformed_test = model.transform(test_corpus)
```

Again, this can only be a guess until you post the `setup_data` function, but having seen this before I would guess you're doing something more like this:

```
model = CountVectorizer()
transformed_train = model.fit_transform(train_corpus)
transformed_test = model.fit_transform(test_corpus)
```

which will effectively make a new vocabulary for the `test_corpus`, which unsurprisingly won't give you the same vocabulary length in both cases.